# Designing a database for storing questions of type match the followings

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I've managed to store question of types long, short, mcq with any number options and any number of answers with following database design.[image]
Now I need to store question of type- Match the following. I'm unable to design a better database for match the following. The match the following will be a question and within it there can be any number of rows to be matched as follows:[image]

Any precious suggestion will be valuable. Thank you.

Comment: What you have designed for this?